# Restore IMac(Late 2015 - 17,1) from Time Machine gets stuck on HD reformat

Tags: hard-drive, backup, time-machine, imac

I tried to update my late 2015 IMac (27" I7 - IMac 17,1) to the latest MacOS version it will support - Monterey. The upgrade failed, leaving my OS in an unbootable state. I am trying to restore now from the most recent Time Machine backup. After booting into the recovery menu, I select re-install from Time Machine, and it says it's going to reformat the target drive - I.e. the internal HD. The format (supposedly) begins, but never gets anywhere - it sits in the same state for hours. The log window shows no progress at all.

I have run first aid on the HD to verify it's okay, and it appears fine. The hardware also seems fine - I'm able successfully to boot off a USB drive I had made a bootable backup on (using SuperDuper!). I did an NVRAM reset too.

Hoping for some assistance, info, steps to try ...

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like disk utility is running into some bad blocks and having a bad time re-allocating them. That is sometimes the cause of the symptoms you are seeing (EG disk errors) A commercially available disk repair utility might at least tell you what is really going on.